# How to judge if two Dataset are equal

Tags: dataset, expression-test

I don's sure this is a bug or not.Suppose I have a `dataset`

```
dataset = 
 Dataset[{{"a", 10}, {"b", 11}, {"c", 12}, {"d", 5}, {"e", 99}}]
```

> [image]

Then we do two same operation on it.

```
{set1 = dataset[All, <|"col1" -> 1, "col2" -> 2|>], 
 set2 = dataset[Map[AssociationThread[{"col1", "col2"} -> #] &]]}
```

> [image]

As we see,we get two data set totally.But in some time,we can not judge it just by our eyes.Let use `==` or `===` to test it.

```
set1 == set2
```

> [image]

```
set1 === set2
```

> `False`

Of course `Equal @@ Normal /@ {set1, set2}` works well,but the `Normal` don't judge two `Dataset` instead of two `List` actually.So I have two question here:

1. Why the `==` and `===` will fail here?
2. Is there any method can judge two datasets are same or not?

Comment: For part 1 compare `FullForm@set1` and `FullForm@set2`. You seem to have answered part 2 yourself.

Comment: It's enough to make you hate metadata. Datasets are becoming a language unto itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the `"ID"` part of the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the datasets, not in the data. So, if you want to compare the data portion, you can use the function:

```
compareDatasets[s1_Dataset, s2_Dataset] := 
  SameQ @@ (Cases[# // FullForm, HoldPattern@Dataset[a_, ___] :> a] & /@ {s1, s2})
```

We can test it on the datasets provided in the OP:

```
compareDatasets[set1, set2]
```

> `True`

```
compareDatasets[set1, dataset[Map[AssociationThread[{"col1", "col3"} -> #] &]]]
```

> `False`

Comment: Yes, the IDs are different (in a system´s point of view), but from a users point of view, the Datasets are equal, so maybe a Query like "DatasetEqualQ" may be useful to increase the usability of Datasets. Maybe we see this in an upcoming version

Comment: This jumps through a lot of hoops where `Equal @@ Normal /@ {set1, set2}` is sufficient and included in the OP.

Comment: I just think the `Equal` should be `True`。But the `Same` give `False`